# PHP add multiple strings within a string at multiple positions

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos

While this works perfectly, looking for a way to make it a little / lot cleaner, and also to learn along the way!!!
I am adding **/thumbs** to a directory and file string, and also adding **_thumb** to the end of the file name of that same string.

from this... Gallery/Test/Image/image.jpg

to this... Gallery/Test/Image/thumbs/image_thumb.jpg

but the paths can change in length depending on the directory structure, but /thumbs will always be the last directory, and _thumb will always be before the "."

```
    $thumb_dir = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '/')) . '/thumbs' . substr($file, strrpos($file, '/'));

    $thumbnail = substr($thumb_dir, 0, strrpos($thumb_dir, '.')) . '_thumb' . substr($thumb_dir, strrpos($thumb_dir, '.'));
```

Thanks

Comment: You can also do it with Regular Expressions: https://3v4l.org/AjNgC I'm not posting it as an answer because the accepted answer is definitely a better solution. But I thought it was an interesting approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) might help you if your PHP version is >  5.2.0+

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('Gallery/Test/Image/image.jpg');
echo $path_parts['dirname'].'/thumbs/'.$path_parts['filename'].'_thumb.'.$path_parts['extension'];
```

**Little explanation of the code**

`$path_parts['dirname']` would fetch the complete directory path of the path given in this case it would be `Gallery/Test/Image`. Then we added a directory called `'/thumbs/'` into the string. next we should get the name of the file using `$path_parts['filename']` which would fetch `image` and not `image.jpg` and furthur we added `'_thumb.'` to it. and later we suffix with the extension.

Comment: I'm on 5.31, so I will give it a try, much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Mohit,
That worked perfectly, thank you!! Also thanks for the explanation, I also read the function documentation!
Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey @Simon. Thanks for the kind words. Happy to help. :)